# Websocket error in speedtest.net/host-tester

Tags: linux, websocket

I'm setting up Ookla Speedtest server but I'm having websocket error "Connection timed out (110)" when using FQDN:808. But when using myIP:8080, websocket testing result is passed. Can anyone help me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. With the little info you provide, it's impossible to help you. Also, I wonder if you're programming some code at all, because if you just use someone else's software, it's not a question for Stack Overflow.